# Add shortcode to WooCommerce product description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, code-snippets

I am trying to auto-add some shortcode at the end of every woo product description. (not after short description). The code with which I am trying is:

```
add_filter('product_descr','ce_add_text_short_descr');
function ce_add_text_short_descr($description){
$text="[my-shortcode-goes-here]";
return $description.$text;
}
```

That one is not working for me. can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_filter('the_content', 'mujuonly_alter_product_description');

function mujuonly_alter_product_description($description) {
    if (is_product()) {
        $text = do_shortcode('[products limit="4" columns="4" orderby="popularity" class="quick-sale" on_sale="true" ]');
        return $description . $text;
    }
  return $description;
}
```

This way using the hook `the_content` you can update the product description using the shortcode

Comment: Thank You. You got the point. Its working fine for single product page but its affecting the shop page. Adding this snippet hided all the products on the shop page. And there it is showing just the header, title and footer. No body content. any help?

Comment: Yor answer is fine. Before all my product got hidden from the shop. and now my posts data got hidden from the single post page. There only image and title is displayed nothing else. I am not getting where is the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description','ts_add_text_short_descr');
function ts_add_text_short_descr($description){
   $text = do_shortcode('[my-custom-text]');
  return $description.$text;
}
```

You are making mistake with woocommerce hook and if we neeed to print a shortcode in a php file it works with do_shortcode(); Hope it will work on your side I have already tested it.
Don't forget to replace my-custom-text with your shortcode.

Comment: Reread the question. I asked about the long description, not the short description.

Comment: @ArbabAli where you wanna show it on the single product page or on the catalog?

Comment: I want to show it on single product page. I added the shared code inside the functions.php it worked fine. But due to adding this code hidded all the post content on a single post page.

Comment: did you try it with the 'template_redirect' hook?